# duplicate template with meteor

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I'm trying to get my head around Meteor basics.
I've created a meteor app (with meteorite)
I have the basics file generated by the start up script

in my html file I have a template:

```
<body>
<h1>test</h1>
  {{#each items}}
    {{> envelop}}
  {{/each}}
</body>

<template name="envelop">
<div class="envelop"><div class="envelop-inner">
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div></div>
</template>
```

Then in my js file i have the following code:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  itemsData = [
    {title: 'test1'},
    {title: 'test2'},
    {title: 'test3'}
  ];
  Template.envelop.helpers ({
    items: itemsData
  });
}
```

I'm trying to have Meteor run through that and duplicate the partials.
I can't seem to make this work, i keep getting errors. or nothing gets printed on the page.

I guess i'm missing a basic thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template your helper is in is the one that will have the data context given by `items`, so just encapsulate it in a template. The `items` helper can only be seen by `envelop` but nothing higher (such as body)

```
<body>
<h1>test</h1>
</body>

<template name="envelop">
  {{#each items}}
    {{>item}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="item">
  <div class="envelop"><div class="envelop-inner">
      <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div></div>
</template>
```

Comment: Magic, thanks man! didn't get that. the other question is Which one are you on the avatar picture?

Comment: Haha I was quite scared when that was taken because it started looking at me